# Facing issue while showing data on view file

Tags: laravel-10

This is index function:
`public function index() {$tasks = Task::all(); return view('dashboard', compact('tasks')); }`

and this is view file:

```
` @foreach ($tasks as $task)
                <td class="p-2">Saeed</td>
                <td class="p-2">{{ $task->title }}</td>
                <td class="p-2">{{ $task->description }}</td>
                <td class="p-2">{{ $task->due_date }}</td>
                <td class="p-2">
                    @if ($task->status)
                        Completed
                    @else
                        Uncompleted
                    @endif
                </td>
            @endforeach`
```

and issue is Undefined variable $tasks.
Can anyone help me to solve this?

I created index function and now want to show all task on view file.